# Deploy por linha de comando

Tags: android, deploy, apk

Estamos criando rotinas de geração e publicação de versão dos apps de forma automática, utilizando o GitFlow e o CI (continuous integration).

Existe alguma forma de fazer o deploy do apk (ele já está gerado e assinado - apenas quero enviar ele para a playstore) por linha de comando no windows/linux?

Comment: @Articuno Não seria uma duplicada, porque quero enviar o .apk já assinado para playstore por linha de comando.